PIN panel giving "wrong PIN" message no matter if PIN is correct or not
I have a task to make PIN panel in GUI which is supposed to check if PIN is correct and give a message "Correct PIN" or "Wrong PIN". I managed to make the whole code, but it returns me "Wrong PIN" message even if I write a correct PIN.
I tried to change type of PIN in string and integer, change a place where I call the function check_pin(), but I get always the same (wrong) input
Code:
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry ('800x300')
root.title('Check PIN')

number1_var = StringVar()

def button_add(number):
    number1 = entry_PIN.get()
    entry_PIN.delete (0, END)
    entry_PIN.insert (0, number1+str(number))

pin = '1234'

def check_PIN():
    number1=number1_var.get()
    if number1 == pin:
        label1 = Label (root, text='Correct PIN!')
        label1.grid(row=6, column=1)
    else:
        label2 = Label (root, text='Wrong PIN!')
        label2.grid(row=7, column=1) 

label_pin = Label (root, text='PIN:')
label_pin.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky='e')

entry_PIN = Entry(root)
entry_PIN.grid (row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

button1 = Button(root, text='1', width=7, command=lambda: button_add(1))
button2 = Button(root, text='2', width=7, command=lambda: button_add(2)) 
button3 = Button(root, text='3', width=7, command=lambda: button_add(3))
button4 = Button(root, text='4', width=7, command=lambda: button_add(4))
button5 = Button(root, text='5', width=7, command=lambda: button_add(5))
button6 = Button(root, text='6', width=7, command=lambda: button_add(6)) 
button7 = Button(root, text='7', width=7, command=lambda: button_add(7))
button8 = Button(root, text='8', width=7, command=lambda: button_add(8))
button9 = Button(root, text='9', width=7, command=lambda: button_add(9)) 

button1.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)
button2.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=10, pady=10)
button3.grid(row=1, column=3, padx=10, pady=10)
button4.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)
button5.grid(row=2, column=2, padx=10, pady=10)
button6.grid(row=2, column=3, padx=10, pady=10)
button7.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)
button8.grid(row=3, column=2, padx=10, pady=10)
button9.grid(row=3, column=3, padx=10, pady=10)

button_check = Button(root, text='Check PIN!', command=lambda:check_PIN())
button_check.grid(row=5, column=1)

root.mainloop()

Thank you for you answers in advance!

You forgot to tell the Entry that you wanted to use a StringVar. You meant to write: entry_PIN = Entry(root, textvariable = number1_var)

You arent setting number1_var anywhere, so number1=number1_var.get() is returning an empty string every time. But apart from that, what you'll want to do in check_PIN is just call entry_PIN.get() instead.
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry ('800x300')
root.title('Check PIN')


def button_add(number):
    number1 = entry_PIN.get()
    entry_PIN.delete (0, END)
    entry_PIN.insert (0, number1+str(number))


pin = '1234'


def check_PIN():
    if entry_PIN.get() == pin:  # get the value from the Entry here
        label1 = Label (root, text='Correct PIN!')
        label1.grid(row=6, column=1)
    else:
        label2 = Label (root, text='Wrong PIN!')
        label2.grid(row=7, column=1) 


label_pin = Label (root, text='PIN:')
label_pin.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky='e')

entry_PIN = Entry(root)
entry_PIN.grid (row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

button1 = Button(root, text='1', width=7, command=lambda: button_add(1))
button2 = Button(root, text='2', width=7, command=lambda: button_add(2)) 
button3 = Button(root, text='3', width=7, command=lambda: button_add(3))
button4 = Button(root, text='4', width=7, command=lambda: button_add(4))
button5 = Button(root, text='5', width=7, command=lambda: button_add(5))
button6 = Button(root, text='6', width=7, command=lambda: button_add(6)) 
button7 = Button(root, text='7', width=7, command=lambda: button_add(7))
button8 = Button(root, text='8', width=7, command=lambda: button_add(8))
button9 = Button(root, text='9', width=7, command=lambda: button_add(9)) 

button1.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)
button2.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=10, pady=10)
button3.grid(row=1, column=3, padx=10, pady=10)
button4.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)
button5.grid(row=2, column=2, padx=10, pady=10)
button6.grid(row=2, column=3, padx=10, pady=10)
button7.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)
button8.grid(row=3, column=2, padx=10, pady=10)
button9.grid(row=3, column=3, padx=10, pady=10)

button_check = Button(root, text='Check PIN!', command=lambda:check_PIN())
button_check.grid(row=5, column=1)

root.mainloop()


Thank you for your input, JRiggles! I'll try to correct it and provide the feedback!

Glad I could help. If this answer works for you, please click the check mark to accept it so that others know this question has been answered.

Checked, works! Thank you once again, JRiggles!

Any time, happy coding!

You could use a loop for all of the buttons…

@DeepThought42 yeah, there’s room for some refactoring here. For stuff like this I like to use a loop and divmod for the row/column calculation
